# C++ How to wprintf an int as wstring

Tags: c++, type-conversion, printf, wstring, wchar

I have the following code. I want it to print the letter A but it gives me 65.

**How do I wprintf the wchar/wstring of this number?**

```
  int aa=65;
  std::wstring ws65 = std::to_wstring(aa);
  wprintf(L"   ws65 = %ls \n", ws65.c_str());
```

Comment: Use `%c` instead of converting to_wstring ?  Or can `aa` be outside of 0-255?

Comment: Why are you using `wprintf` instead of `std::wcout`?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve. Form of your code is strange suggesting that you trimmed question to much.

Comment: Since wsprintf expects wide strings use %s instead, use %ls for printf

Comment: If you use C++20 use [std::wformat](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) and std::wcout, or C++23 std::print. But I really would recommend not to use printf or wprintf anymore for safety reasons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert to string first, just do this:

```
int aa=65;
wprintf(L"   ws65 = %c \n", aa);
```

That's much more efficient, as you avoid an extra string allocation, construction, and copy.

Or if you want to use `wcout`, which is the "more C++" way:

```
std::wcout <<  L"   ws65 = " << static_cast<wchar_t>(aa) << std::endl;
```

Comment: I suspect `wchar_t` was not fixed in copy paste.

Comment: They want `A` to be printed, not `65`.

Comment: In `wprintf()`, `%c` expects `wchar_t` not `int`.  Need to use `%lc` to accept `int` and convert it to `wchar_t`, otherwise just cast the `int` to `wchar_t` before passing it in.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: On what platform does that matter?  On x86-64 with Apple clang 14.0.0 it builds and runs as I wrote it, even with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck `wchar_t != int`, and `sizeof(wchar_t) != sizeof(int)` on every platform.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are wrong, here is proof: https://godbolt.org/z/63Gf8Y7hz .  As for %c vs %lc, it does not matter because `65` converts to `65` with `%c` just fine.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I said they are not the same on *every* platform. Your "proof" is only looking at 1 specific compiler on 1 specific platform. `sizeof(wchar_t)` is `2` on every Windows compiler, for instance, because Microsoft uses `wchar_t` for UTF-16 (and UCS-2 before that), whereas just about every other platform uses `wchar_t` for UTF-32 instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Your phrasing was very ambiguous.  I understand what you're saying now.  I don't promise that the code I wrote in my answer is portable to all platforms.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert an `int` to a single-character `std::wstring`, you can just use `std::wstring`'s constructor instead of `std::to_wstring`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main() {
    int aa = 65;
    std::wstring ws65 = std::wstring(1, aa);
    std::wcout <<  L"   ws65 = " << ws65 << L'\n';
}
```

which outputs

```
ws65 = A
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::to_wstring()` just converts the input into the actual written out number (ie: 123 becomes "123"). `printf()` and `wprintf()` are nice because they look at the data you give it in whatever way you specify, so since the actual binary for 'A' and the number 65 are the same, you can just tell it to read the data as a character, no conversions necessary:

```
int aa=65;
wprintf(L"   ws65 = %lc \n", aa);
```